# Проблема с библиотекой yadisk для работы с Rest API

Tags: python, rest, yandex-disk

Для проекта решил взять себе тему с Рест Апи, именно связанную с Яндекс.Диском.
Наткнулся на библиотеку-клиент yadisk, вначале попробовал, всё шло нормально.
Сегодня пытаюсь выполнить некоторые команды, но натыкаюсь на какие-то ненормальные вещи.

Допустим: по библиотеке метод `upload(path_or_file, dst_path, **kwargs)` Загружает файл на диск.

Параметры:
`path_or_file` – путь к файлу или файл-подобный объект для загрузки
`dst_path` – путь назначения
Хорошо, моя функция:

```
def upload(y, from_, to_, *kwargs):
    operation = y.upload(from_, to_)
```

работает, проверил, НО, почему программа после заливки файла на яндекс диск, игнорируя путь `to_`
просто заливает файл в главную директорию, а вместо этого пути (`to_`) даёт ему название, хотя это должен был быть путь?

Такие фейлы у меня не только с этой командой, но описания основной, думаю, должно быть достаточно первой будет достаточно.
Мой код:

```
import sys
import yadisk
import os
import pyAesCrypt
from os import stat, remove
import random


def upload(y, from_, to_, *kwargs):
    operation = y.upload(from_, to_)

def mkdir(y, path, **kwargs):
    try:
        operation = y.mkdir(path)
        print('Status: success')
    except:
        print('Не выполнено, ошибка')

def move(y, from_path, to_path):
    operation = y.move(from_path, to_path)
    while True:
        status = y.get_operation_status(operation.href)
        if status == "in-progress":
            time.sleep(5)
            print("Still waiting...")
        elif status == "success":
            print("Success")
            break
        else:
            print("Не выполнено, ошибка: {0}".format(status))

y = yadisk.YaDisk("94885fad3a5e407b8cda5af348597aae", "59d96c74713947b9bad0f691dffb5699")
url = y.get_code_url()
# with open("data.txt", "rb") as token_txt:
#    code = token_txt
code = input('Введите код: ')
try:
    response = y.get_token(code)
    print('n1')
except yadisk.exceptions.BadRequestError:
    print('n2')
    sys.exit(1)
y.token = response.access_token
print('n3')

if y.check_token():
    print("Токен получен")
else:
    print("Срок жизни токена истек, либо введён не правильно")
```

подаю переменные: `upload(y, 'D:\\aurora\\lolz.jpg', '\\test-dir')`
Так что это за фигня? Может алгоритмы ЯндексДиска изменились? Просто эту библиотеку не обновляли больше года. Заранее спасибо!
Документация на библиотеку: https://yadisk.readthedocs.io/ru/latest/intro.html

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, значение `to_` в вопрос, нажав кнопку [edit].

Comment: Добавил, после кода

Comment: Попробуйте заменить `to_` на `/test-dir/lolz.jpg`. Файлы могут не иметь расширений, возможно поэтому Яндекс распознал `test-dir` как имя файла, который требуется загрузить в корневой каталог.

Comment: Да, вы абсолютно правы, большое спасибо за помощь! дедлайн через 3 часа

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Укажите в параметре `_to` полный путь до файла.

***Пример:***

```
/test-dir/lolz.jpg
```

---

Файлы могут не иметь расширений, поэтому `/test-dir` можно интерпретировать как файл `test-dir` в корневом каталоге.